# How to get the cell_id from cell content in Google Sheet API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For example i want to search this exact text "FOO" and i want to know where it is present in google sheet through Google Sheet API

urrently i am accessing all sheet content and looping it and mtching with my search qyery to get the row number

Comment: In which language are you trying it? Java or Node.js or Python?

Comment: Also post some code that you have written to achieve the desired goal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently i am using below line
```python
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, range=f"{sheet_name}!B:B").execute().get('values', [])
```
After i have to loop through each element and match with my order_ID with cell content